# Store and Use Configuaration values in Alfresco Share

Tags: share, alfresco

I have a custom developed share dashlet that has hardcoded values in use (For example the name of a Workspace to use as a default).

I would rather have the values placed into a configuration file and have the dashlet read the fileup at server start and work from there. I have two questions:

- Which file can I use and where can I place the file?
- How can I get the share dashlet to read the file contents and load the data into local variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to leverage the [PreferenceService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/preference/PreferenceService.html), which can be accessed from a Share Web Script by consuming the following API exposed by the repository:

```
GET /cms-repository-5.0.0/service/api/people/{userid}/preferences?pf={preferencefilter?}
POST /cms-repository-5.0.0/service/api/people/{userid}/preferences?pf={preferencefilter?}
DELETE /cms-repository-5.0.0/service/api/people/{userid}/preferences?pf={preferencefilter?}
```

In this way you will probably need to define some hard coded meaningful defaults, then let the user customize his experience and store the customized settings as user preferences.